# Avisar quando um tempo for diferente do outro

Tags: javascript

Olá, tenho duas `vars` armazenando dois tempos no formato `minutos:segundos:milisegundos`:

```
var tempo1 = "11:10:10";
var tempo2 = "11:10:10";
```

Gostaria de gerar um alerta quando o `tempo1` for dirente(maior ou menor) em 0,5seg do `tempo2`.

Comment: E você terá valores decimais nos segundos? Pode [edit] a pergunta e colocar o que já tentou fazer e escrever a dificuldade encontrada?

Comment: Ainda não fiz nada, estou perdido em como iniciar essa comparação, valores decimais no segundo

Comment: Esses 3 parametros de tempo são horas, minutos e segundos? ou minutos, segundos, milisegundos?

Comment: @DvD eu não percebi como é que se pode detectar diferenças de menos de um segundo se o grau de exatidão do input é 1 segundo (no caso de ser `hh:mm:ss`). Daí a dúvida se o ultimo parâmetro seria  milisegundos...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Se o teu input é `minutos:segundos:milisegundos` podes saber se a diferênça entre os dois é menos que `300ms` por exemplo assim:

```js
function diff300(a, b) {
  a = a.split(':').map(Number);
  b = b.split(':').map(Number);
  return Math.abs(
      new Date(2000, 0, 1, 1, ...a) - new Date(2000, 0, 1, 1, ...b)
  ) > 300;
}

console.log(diff300("11:10:10", "11:10:10")); console.log(diff300("11:10:10", "11:10:510"));
```

A ideia é criar duas datas com os minutos, segundos e milisegundos como única diferênça e depois verificar se a diferênça absoluta entre elas é menor que `300ms`

Answer (score 5):

Mais abaixo, segue uma **resposta alternativa** e **mais curta**. **E** também **mais econômica** em recursos.

A função recebe três argumentos, em ordem:

- tempo 1
- tempo 2
- valor a ser comparado em milissegundos (500, neste caso)

Se não precisar de algo *genérico* (sempre 500ms), pode-se retirar o 3º argumento. Mas não esquecer de trocar em todos os locais dentro da função, de forma apropriada, por 500 onde havia o nome do terceiro argumento.

Ao converter os tempos para `Date`, precisa-se colocar dados falsos para zona de tempo e dia, mês e ano. Não interfere com o resultado já que esses dados extras são iguais para ambos os casos.

A função retorna `true` para casos em que a diferença seja maior ou menor que o valor especificado no 3º argumento. Retorna `false` caso seja exatamente e igual ao valor especificado.

A forma de lidar com o resultado fica ao gosto do freguês. Se quiser usar `alert()` ou outros recursos, basta alterar.

```js
// Tempos armazenados a serem verificados
var tempo_1 = "13:12:11";
var tempo_2 = "13:12:12";

// Função verificadora de diferença
function dif_ms(tempo_1, tempo_2, comparativo) {

  // Converte os tempos para o tipo `Date` e obtme tempo total em milissegundos
  var t1 = new Date("2000-01-01T" + tempo_1 + "Z").getTime();
  var t2 = new Date("2000-01-01T" + tempo_2 + "Z").getTime();

  // Verifica a diferença
  var delta = Math.abs(t1 - t2);

  // Retorna 'true' se for diferente (maior ou menor) que 500ms ou 0.5s
  return delta != comparativo;

}

// Exemplo de saída
console.log("- É diferente de 500ms (ou 0,5s)? \n- " + (dif_ms(tempo_1, tempo_2, 500) ? "Sim." : "Não."));
```

Comment: Haha, respondemos no mesmo minuto, com mais ou menos a mesma ideia :) `+1`

Comment: @Sergio LOL! Acabo de ver, haha! *high five* Mas devo dizer que a sua é mais elegante! ;)

Comment: Como é que se coloca esses exemplos e execução de código aqui no Stack Overflow?

Comment: @Ramos ao fazer a pergunta (ou resposta), vai ter um botão ao lado direito do botão de inserção de imagem. Ele apresenta "< >" desenhado nele. Ao clicar, vai abrir um "modal" (imitação de janela) nos moldes do JSFiddle. Aí é só colocar o código no local apropriado (CSS, HTML e JavaScript).

Comment: @José Obrigado! Vou usar.